# How can I, case insensitive, replace all occurences of needle in a MySQL table haystack?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace, case-insensitive

I have a table with lots of rows with lots of text. In the text fields there are (multiple) occurrences of imagenames wich are 'wrong' due to upper- and undercast letter usage.
I can iterate throug my image directories using PHP and get the real image names (all undercast).
How can I now replace the 'wrong' names in the text fields with the right ones.
I tried to write my own script, but it doesnt quit do the trick. Am I missing somthing?

```
foreach($dir_array as $item) {
$rename = strtolower(basename($item));
$query = "SELECT tekst_id, tekst_tekst FROM tekst WHERE tekst_tekst LIKE '%".$rename."%'";
if($dbresult = mysql_query($query,$dbLink)) {
    $rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult);
    $strMain = $rij["tekst_tekst"];
    $strMain = preg_replace("/($rename+)/i", $rename, $strMain);
    $query2 = "UPDATE tekst SET tekst_tekst = '".$strMain."' WHERE tekst_id = ".$rij["tekst_id"];
    if($dbresult2 = mysql_query($query2,$dbLink)) {
        echo $item.'<br />';
    }
}
```

}

So I want to change all occurences of "ThisIsAName.Jpg" to "thisisaname.jpg" but the rest of the text must stay as is.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - I could not find a answer in previous questions...

Comment: You're querying for `$rename` rather than the value to rename (`basename($item)`). The `+` in your preg_replace is probably not necessary (it matches repetitions of the last character). And you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions as they're deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or preferably PDO.

Comment: Thank you @Kenny, I know mysql_* functions are depricated, but this one is running on a very old local machine with php 5.3 :-/  I tried it with and without the +, still no result.